# Dart pub build giving memory error on Koding

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub, koding

I setup my Polymer.Dart based project on [Koding.com](http://koding.com). All went well and I was able to install the Dart SDK. But when I ran the 'pub build' command after 'pub get' it gives me following error?

> Failed to compile a snapshot to
>   .pub/transformers/transformers.snapshot: runtime/vm/scavenger.cc:461:
>   error: Out of memory.

Does that mean my VM on Koding is out of RAM?

Comment: You could try the recently added `--no-precompile` option https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1396. I don't know if this really helps.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried but this option is not available yet.

Comment: I'd create a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to RAM assigned to my app. Since it was under free tier the RAM amount was limited. It needs more RAM to perform the operation.